# Безопасность подключения к БД на странице

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется страница name.php, на ней вывод информации с БД блоками
Сначала идет вызов настроек через require, потом запрос к БД

```
require_once 'bdcon.php';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `prices` ORDER BY `id` DESC';
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
```

Насколько это безопасно?

Comment: безопасно на 146% (плюс-минус)

Comment: Если все останется в таком виде как сейчас, то вполне безопасно, если добавятся какие либо параметры в sql запрос, то все уже будет зависеть от того, откуда эти параметры будут браться и как будут обрабатываться